# How do i return custom error message in the generic list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, generic-list

I'm new to C# language PLEASE HELP. **I want if the model is empty to return this message** I get an error

Code:

```
public List<PatQuery> GetPatientslist(PatQuery PatQmodel)
    {
        if(PatQmodel != null)
        {
            var mem_no = PatQmodel.memberno;
            var results = _database.Query<PatQuery>("Select * from pat_data where memberno=@0 ", mem_no);
            List<PatQuery> list = results.ToList();
            return list;
        }
      else
        {
            AddMessage("E0000", "null request.", CMessageType.Error);
            return;
        }

    }
```

Message is something like this.

```
private void AddMessage(string _Code, string _Message, CMessageType _MessageType)
    {
        validateRes.Add(new CMessage()
        {
            Code = _Code,
            Message = _Message,
            MessageType = _MessageType

        });
    }
```

its true there are other things i do with message like **validateRes** but is it possible to return this messege

Comment: If you talking about returning a message to a View I would suggest a ViewBag

Answer (score 0):

Pass the error message into a ViewBag and then show message in View.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    modelType model = new modelType()
    //GetModel here
    If(model == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "Emtpy Model";
    }

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@if(ViewBag.ErrorMsg != null)
{
    <label>@ViewBag.ErrorMsg</label>
}
```

You could also just throw an `HttpException` like this:

```
throw new HttpException(400, "No data was found");
```